# Last blank row merging issue in SSRS Report on exporting in Excel format

Tags: reporting-services

[image]Here I am using SSRS version **Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 12.0.5207.0**

Created a simple SSRS report with single table. The Report is having 5 columns and 1 row without any grouping.

When I am exporting it in excel format, I get the last row merging issue. Its random occurrence doesn't know the reason why it is happening.

Please check the snapshot for more details (**Red** circle). Row no 299 is merged.

Comment: One possible cause is in your Designer.  If the divider between the Body and Footer is not moved up to the the base of the tablix it could cause this to occur when exported to Excel.

Comment: We are not using any header or footer in my report. There is only **singe table without any grouping**.

Answer (score 0):

@user2269520 this is what I was referring to.  Even if you have no header or footer, the divider is still there and if not flush, it sometimes adds a margin to the bottom of the table. It may not be your situation but it is just a thought.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will get the merging issue when export excel, If any space/gap between tablix and report body,report footer or any controls.

[image: Report design and export excel]